# How to add an extra channel to tiff in C# from another tiff image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff

I need to add an extra channel (spot color perphaps) to tiff image from another grayscale tiff. The channels of result image must be seen in Photoshop like this:

[image: channels view]

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
static public void getGrayOverlayLBA(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        Size s1 = bmp1.Size;
        Size s2 = bmp2.Size;
        if (s1 != s2) return;

        PixelFormat fmt1 = bmp1.PixelFormat;
        PixelFormat fmt2 = bmp2.PixelFormat;

        PixelFormat fmt = new PixelFormat();
        fmt = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
        Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(s1.Width, s1.Height, fmt);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, s1.Width, s1.Height);

        BitmapData bmp1Data = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt1);
        BitmapData bmp2Data = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt2);
        BitmapData bmp3Data = bmp3.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, fmt);

        byte bpp1 = 4;
        byte bpp2 = 4;
        byte bpp3 = 4;

        if (fmt1 == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) bpp1 = 3;
        else if (fmt1 == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb || fmt1 == PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb) bpp1 = 4; else return;
        if (fmt2 == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) bpp2 = 3;
        else if (fmt2 == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) bpp2 = 4; else return;

        int size1 = bmp1Data.Stride * bmp1Data.Height;
        int size2 = bmp2Data.Stride * bmp2Data.Height;
        int size3 = bmp3Data.Stride * bmp3Data.Height;
        byte[] data1 = new byte[size1];
        byte[] data2 = new byte[size2];
        byte[] data3 = new byte[size3];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp1Data.Scan0, data1, 0, size1);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp2Data.Scan0, data2, 0, size2);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp3Data.Scan0, data3, 0, size3);

        for (int y = 0; y < s1.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
            {
                int index1 = y * bmp1Data.Stride + x * bpp1;
                int index2 = y * bmp2Data.Stride + x * bpp2;
                int index3 = y * bmp3Data.Stride + x * bpp3;
                Color c1, c2;

                if (bpp1 == 4)
                    c1 = Color.FromArgb(data1[index1 + 3], data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
                else c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
                if (bpp2 == 4)
                    c2 = Color.FromArgb(data2[index2 + 3], data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);
                else c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);

                byte A = (byte)(255 * c2.GetBrightness());
                data3[index3 + 0] = c1.B;
                data3[index3 + 1] = c1.G;
                data3[index3 + 2] = c1.R;
                data3[index3 + 3] = A;
            }
        }

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data3, 0, bmp3Data.Scan0, data3.Length);
        bmp1.UnlockBits(bmp1Data);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bmp2Data);
        bmp3.UnlockBits(bmp3Data);
        if (File.Exists("result.tiff"))
            File.Delete("result.tiff");
        bmp3.Save("result.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }
```

But my result image has strange transparency over the whole image and no extra channels as expected. Both pictures have the same size. What I'm doing wrong? Are there any free library for the C# which can do this?

Expected result:
[image]

My result:
[image]

**UPD**. Added source files.

Source tiff:[image]

Grayscale tiff to add in source as extra channel:
[image]

**UPD2**. Updated expected result image.

Comment: Uh. Are you sure you mean a 'channel'? Channels are an intrinsic result of the way the image is built from colour components. If you have a Red, Green and Blue channel and you add a fourth, then yes, that fourth will be the only remaining option... an Alpha channel, adding transparency to the image. The variable in that code is even specifically indicated as "A", and the colour format is specifically upgraded from RGB to ARGB. You show the _results_, but what is your _input_? Because I don't think what you want to do is in any way related to channels.

Comment: @nyerguds I need to do it in described way. But I am confused in definitions of alpha channel or spot channel

Comment: Your expected result, as far as I can see, _has_ no alpha channel. So why are you adding an alpha channel? As I said, alpha channel = transparency. Or, rather, opaqueness, really: the lower the alpha, the more transparent something is. And that "grayscale tiff to add as channel" is not one channel; it is both brightness information _and_ alpha; it has transparency of its own visible in the editor.

Comment: @nyerguds so how is called the fifth layer on the first screenshot named "WHITE_INK"? Can it be a spot color channel or some other extra channel? I need to add the same to my source image from grayscale tiff.

Comment: You talked about a "spot channel". That [seems to be related to Photoshop's internal workings](http://blog.jakprints.com/how-to-setup-white-ink-spot-colors/how-to-setup-white-ink-spot-color-in-adobe-photoshop), but it has no bearing on how images are actually _saved_. Photoshop just likes to separate everything into grayscale "channels" even if they are not real channels in a final image file. You have not given enough information here to know exactly what such a "spot channel" does, though, and how to reproduce it in c#.

Comment: If you post actual png images of your sources and your desired result, maybe people can figure out what it is you want to do.

Comment: @nyerguds I posted all information that I have.Maybe I don't understand my task and described it badly.

Comment: Your "Grayscale tiff" at the end is _not just grayscale_. It is grayscale _with visible transparency_. That is at least _two_ channels that could possibly be taken from that. If you post the actual bare file, it would clear up that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're trying this for Print Quality and as far as understood this cannot be done through any programming language. But we can alpha channel through java/python or even through C#. So alternative option is make photoshop action and do the work through Photoshop JSX script (For Bulk conversion). In case if you want to do one by one then simply use the action play from photoshop itself.